# scrapy not giving any output

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I was following this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21993674/scrapy-weird-output) and i was able to run a basespider successfully.

How ever when i tried using the same with a crawlspider, i was not getting any output.

My spider is as follows:

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.http import request
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from medsynergies.items import MedsynergiesItem

class medsynergiesspider(CrawlSpider):

    name="medsynergies"
    allowed_domains=['msi-openhire.silkroad.com/epostings/']
    start_urls=['https://msi-openhire.silkroad.com/epostings/index.cfm?fuseaction=app.jobsearch']

    rules=(
    Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=("jobsearch",))),
    Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=("jobinfo&jobid",)),callback="parse_job",follow=True),
    )

    def parse_job(self, response):
        hxs=HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    titles=hxs.select('//*[@id="jobDesciptionDiv"]')
    items = []

    for titles in titles:
        item=MedsynergiesItem()
        item['job_id']=response.url
        item['title']=titles.select('normalize-space(//*[@id="jobTitleDiv"]/text())').extract()
        item['tracking_code']=titles.select('normalize-space(//*[@id="trackCodeDiv"]/text())').extract()
        item['job_description']=titles.select('.//p/text()').extract()
        item['responsibilities']=titles.select('.//ul/li/text()').extract()
        item['required_skills']=titles.select('normalize-space(//*[@id="jobRequiredSkillsDiv"]/ul)').extract()
        item['job_location']=titles.select('normalize-space(//*[@id="jobPositionLocationDiv"]/text())').extract()
        item['position_type']=titles.select('normalize-space(//*[@id="translatedJobPostingTypeDiv"]/text())').extract()
        items.append(item)
    print items
    return items
```

The output i was getting was as follows:

```
abhishek@abhishek-VirtualBox:~/projects/medsynergies$ scrapy crawl medsynergies > output.txt
2014-02-24 17:18:07-0700 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 0.22.1 started (bot: medsynergies)
2014-02-24 17:18:07-0700 [scrapy] INFO: Optional features available: ssl, http11, boto, django
2014-02-24 17:18:07-0700 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'medsynergies.spiders', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['medsynergies.spiders'], 'BOT_NAME': 'medsynergies'}
2014-02-24 17:18:07-0700 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled extensions: LogStats, TelnetConsole, CloseSpider, WebService, CoreStats, SpiderState
2014-02-24 17:18:07-0700 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAuthMiddleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMiddleware, RetryMiddleware, DefaultHeadersMiddleware, MetaRefreshMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, RedirectMiddleware, CookiesMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
2014-02-24 17:18:07-0700 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
2014-02-24 17:18:07-0700 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines: 
2014-02-24 17:18:07-0700 [medsynergies] INFO: Spider opened
2014-02-24 17:18:07-0700 [medsynergies] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2014-02-24 17:18:07-0700 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 0.0.0.0:6023
2014-02-24 17:18:07-0700 [scrapy] DEBUG: Web service listening on 0.0.0.0:6080
2014-02-24 17:18:16-0700 [medsynergies] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://msi-openhire.silkroad.com/epostings/index.cfm?fuseaction=app.jobinfo&jobid=1284&source=ONLINE&JobOwner=992700&company_id=16616&version=1&byBusinessUnit=NULL&bycountry=0&bystate=0&byRegion=&bylocation=NULL&keywords=&byCat=NULL&proximityCountry=&postalCode=&radiusDistance=&isKilometers=&tosearch=yes> (referer: None) ['partial']
2014-02-24 17:18:16-0700 [medsynergies] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2014-02-24 17:18:16-0700 [medsynergies] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
    {'downloader/request_bytes': 496,
     'downloader/request_count': 1,
     'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
     'downloader/response_bytes': 6637,
     'downloader/response_count': 1,
     'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
     'finish_reason': 'finished',
     'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 25, 0, 18, 16, 171093),
     'log_count/DEBUG': 3,
     'log_count/INFO': 7,
     'response_received_count': 1,
     'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
     'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
     'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
     'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
     'start_time': datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 25, 0, 18, 7, 451729)}
2014-02-24 17:18:16-0700 [medsynergies] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Please let me know where i am doing the mistake. If my rules are too strict, how do i change them such that they scrape?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not about your `rules`, the problem is in `allowed_domains`:

```
allowed_domains = ['msi-openhire.silkroad.com']
```

Also, note that your `parse()` function contains a serious problem. You are overwriting the `titles`. Replace:

```
for titles in titles:
```

with:

```
for title in titles:
```

And every item field definition should use `title`.

Also, note that `HtmlXPathSelector` and `select()` are deprecated, use [`Selector`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#scrapy.selector.Selector) and [`xpath()`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#scrapy.selector.Selector.xpath).

Comment: @crozzfire great, I wish every scrapy question would be like this: clear and informative. Thanks.

Comment: Hi. Can you help me in this question??http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24676624/django-execute-and-pass-json-data-by-executing-a-postgresql-function