# python scrapy FormRequest.FormResponse not giving any output

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

Very new to coding and especially new to scrapy.

I have simple scraper writen with "scrapy". I have written it in hope to produce a list of options (from 'x' element). But it dosen't provide anything. I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24289854/3604513) but failed to get any way ahead in solving issue I am facing.

I am pasting the full code followed by full output.
(note: in setting.py I have changed robottext=True to robottext to False)

```
from scrapy import FormRequest
import scrapy

class FillFormSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'fill_form'
    allowed_domains = ['citizen.mahapolice.gov.in/Citizen/MH/PublishedFIRs.aspx']
    start_urls = ['http://citizen.mahapolice.gov.in/Citizen/MH/PublishedFIRs.aspx/']

    def parse(self, response):
        yield FormRequest.from_response(
            response,
            formid='form1',
            formdata={
                'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtDateOfRegistrationFrom': "01/07/2020",
                'ContentPlaceHolder1_txtDateOfRegistrationTo': "03/07/2020",
                'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlDistrict': "19372"},
            callback=(self.after_login)
        )

    def after_login(self, response):
        print(response.xpath('//*[@id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlPoliceStation"]/text()'))
```

And the out put in terminal after running the command `scrapy crawl spider_name`:

```
2020-07-12 21:32:21 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 2.2.0 started (bot: maha_police)
2020-07-12 21:32:21 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.5.0.0, libxml2 2.9.10, cssselect 1.1.0, parsel 1.6.0, w3lib 1.22.0, Twisted 20.3.0, Python 3.8.2 (default, Apr 27 2020, 15:53:34) - [GCC 9.3.0], pyOpenSSL 19.1.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020), cryptography 2.8, Platform Linux-5.4.0-40-generic-x86_64-with-glibc2.29
2020-07-12 21:32:21 [scrapy.utils.log] DEBUG: Using reactor: twisted.internet.epollreactor.EPollReactor
2020-07-12 21:32:21 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings:
{'BOT_NAME': 'maha_police',
 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'maha_police.spiders',
 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['maha_police.spiders']}
2020-07-12 21:32:21 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: 02d86496f7d27542
2020-07-12 21:32:21 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.memusage.MemoryUsage',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2020-07-12 21:32:22 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2020-07-12 21:32:22 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2020-07-12 21:32:22 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2020-07-12 21:32:22 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2020-07-12 21:32:22 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2020-07-12 21:32:22 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2020-07-12 21:32:25 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET https://citizen.mahapolice.gov.in/Citizen/MH/index.aspx> from <GET http://citizen.mahapolice.gov.in/Citizen/MH/PublishedFIRs.aspx/>
2020-07-12 21:32:25 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://citizen.mahapolice.gov.in/Citizen/MH/index.aspx> (referer: None)
2020-07-12 21:32:26 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'citizen.mahapolice.gov.in': <POST https://citizen.mahapolice.gov.in/Citizen/MH/index.aspx>
2020-07-12 21:32:26 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2020-07-12 21:32:26 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 501,
 'downloader/request_count': 2,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 2,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 8149,
 'downloader/response_count': 2,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/302': 1,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 3.542722,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 12, 16, 2, 26, 43681),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 3,
 'log_count/INFO': 10,
 'memusage/max': 54427648,
 'memusage/startup': 54427648,
 'offsite/domains': 1,
 'offsite/filtered': 1,
 'request_depth_max': 1,
 'response_received_count': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 2,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 2,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 2,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 2,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 12, 16, 2, 22, 500959)}
```

I wanted to get list of police stations. So I tried to extract text from related element. Where am I going wrong? Also it I want to click on search, how should I proceed? Thanks for kind help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in this line:

```
2020-07-12 21:32:26 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'citizen.mahapolice.gov.in': <POST https://citizen.mahapolice.gov.in/Citizen/MH/index.aspx>
```

Your request is being filtered. In your case, since it's filtered because it's considered an offsite by the `OffsiteMiddleware`. I suggest you to change your `allowed_domains` from:

```
allowed_domains = ['citizen.mahapolice.gov.in/Citizen/MH/PublishedFIRs.aspx']
```

to:

```
allowed_domains = ['citizen.mahapolice.gov.in']
```

**This change alone already worked for me, so it's a preferable solution**.

If you check the [docs](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Spider.allowed_domains) you will see that this field is supposed to contain  the **domains** that this spider is allowed to crawl.

What is happening to your spider is that the `OffsiteMiddleware` compiles a regex with the domains in `allowed_domains` field and while processing the requests it checks the method `should_follow` ([code](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/offsite.py)) to know if the request should be executed. The regex would return `None`, and it would cause it to be filtered.

You could also use the `dont_filter` [parameter](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#request-objects) when building your request, this would also work, however the solution above is better. It would look like this:

```
        yield FormRequest.from_response(
            response,
            formid='form1',
            formdata={
                'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtDateOfRegistrationFrom': "01/07/2020",
                'ContentPlaceHolder1_txtDateOfRegistrationTo': "03/07/2020",
                'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlDistrict': "19372"},
            callback=self.after_login,
            dont_filter=True, # <<< Here 
        )
```

Comment: Thanks. But I failed to understand this- you have asked me to change allowed domains. But the one which you have suggested is already there. Am I missing something?

Comment: @sangharsh I suggested you to use **only** the domain in your `allowed_domains` field, instead of using the full url. Will add more detail to the answer.

Comment: Got the point! Thanks. Also if I want to populate list of police stations from the response, how should I go? Can you suggest anything??

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, I suggest you to open a new question and add more details what you want to do and what you tried and didn't work. As I tested your spider I didn't got the list response, the most common issue is that the `from_response` method is including fields in the body that shouldn't be there. You can check this by printing `response.request.body` and compare it with your browser's request. Sometimes mimicking the request's headers is also needed.

Comment: I have started another question - https://stackoverflow.com/q/62912458/3604513